# Android Studio error in Linux as Could Not access Package manager

Tags: android, linux

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: AVD_for_Nexus_4 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: /home/verma/AndroidStudioProjects/Icandy1/App/build/apk/App-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.google.icandy1.app
Installing com.google.icandy1.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.google.icandy1.app"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

I got the above errors. Could anyone please solve this issue from Android Studio.

Comment: What did you try so far? Waht did you do the get this error?

Comment: I did all the required installations and while running my project in Android Studio i get the above error that the package manager could not be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62113. From the bug report:

> Our theory is that the IDE is trying to install the APK while the
>   emulator is still starting up, before it's ready to have things
>   installed in it. If that theory is correct, we need to have the IDE do
>   better detection of what state the emulator is in and have it wait
>   until it's ready; in the meantime, try working around it by launching
>   the emulator by hand, letting it get to the lockscreen and unlocking
>   it, and then leaving it running while you iteratively build and launch
>   apps from the IDE.